# Where is the search option on the mobile sites?

Tags: support, search, mobile-web

I have been unable to locate a search option anywhere on the site. I'm using an iPhone five to view the site. Am I just overlooking the option to search somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the arrow in the top right hand corner. A search box will appear (the white box that, admittedly, doesn't look much like a search box). Use enter on your keyboard to submit.

[image]

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. My thumb was covering it up after I hit the arrow...thx

Comment: Heh, even if your thumb wasn't so big, it's still not the most obvious textbox/ search area ;).